# How to get notifications from .net core or express backend to react js frontend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using fetch() in javascript to fetch data from my .net core backend (will later be replaced with node and express) to my react js front end. With this I can do stuff like http GET and POST, etc. But I need to also be able to get notifications/send messages from the backend when something changes. I assume I need to use something else. What do you recommend? SignalR? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

What u r looking for would be real-time communication

For Node/Express I'd recommend Socket.IO
https://socket.io/

Comment: My backend is .net core 3.0. Is there a socket.io library for that somewhere?